# Doxygen Alias not working in php function after raw html

Tags: php, html, alias, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen to document my php project and have set up a few aliases. They're working fine most of the time, but when it encounters them in a Function level block that is after a function with raw HTML, it complains that its an unknown hook (warning: Found unknown command '\hook'). I have it working in several different files, but anywhere that it's after this raw HTML, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Simplified file:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file foo.php
 * Some description.
 *
 * @since       1.0.0
 * @author      Me
 * @hook        init  //This one works
 */

/**
 * Simple description.
 *
 * Long description.
 *
 * @class   Bar
 * @since   1.0.0
 * @author  Me
 * @hook    init  //This one works
 */
class Bar{

    /**
     * Description.
     *
     * @hook    init  //This one works
     * @since   1.0.0
     */
    function foobar1(){
        //Do stuff here...
    }

    /**
     * Description.
     *
     * @since   1.0.0
     */
    function html(){
        $url = "https://www.website.com/path";

        if($some_condition): ?>

            <div class="notice notice-info">
                <h2>Welcome!</h2>
                <p>If you need access to a site, additional permissions or you've found a bug, please visit <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank">this link</a></p>
            </div>

        <?php endif;
    }

    /**
     * Description.
     *
     * @hook    init  //This one doesn't work
     * @since   1.0.0
     */
    function foobar2(){
        //Do stuff here...
    }
}
```

These are the fields (except input and things like that) that are modified in my Doxyfile:

```
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = YES

ALIASES                = Block="@par Block name^^"
ALIASES                += Description="@par Block description^^"
ALIASES                += hook="@par Hook^^"

EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES

SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = NO

SHOW_NAMESPACES        = NO

#Using this to keep Doxygen from thinking reserved php words are variables
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        =  if
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        += elseif
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        += endif
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        += for
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        += endfor
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        += foreach
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        += endforeach
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        += while
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        += endwhile
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        += <?php
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        += ?>
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        += <script>
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        += </script>
```

My code example shows the Hook alias, but its the same story for any of them.

Update: It seems to have something to do with the fact that the function is below another one that has raw html in it. I've updated the code accordingly.

Update: I've updated the problematic function with HTML that is closer to what I am actually using. As requested, here is the output on this file when running `doxygen -d commentscan`

```
CommentScanner: C:/path/bar.php:2
input=[
@file bar.php
Some description.

@since       1.0.0
@author      Me
@par Hook\_linebr         init  //This one works
]
-----------
CommentScanner: C:/path/bar.php:2
output=[
brief=[line=2
]
docs=[line=3
Some description.

@since       1.0.0
@author      Me
@par Hook
init  //This one works]
inbody=[line=-1
]
]
===========
-----------
CommentScanner: C:/path/bar.php:11
input=[
Simple description.

Long description.

@class   Bar
@since   1.0.0
@author  Me
@par Hook\_linebr     init  //This one works
]
-----------
CommentScanner: C:/path/bar.php:11
output=[
brief=[line=11
Simple description.]
docs=[line=13
Long description.


@since   1.0.0
@author  Me
@par Hook
init  //This one works]
inbody=[line=-1
]
]
===========
-----------
CommentScanner: C:/path/bar.php:23
input=[
Description.

@par Hook\_linebr     init  //This one works
@since   1.0.0
]
-----------
CommentScanner: C:/path/bar.php:23
output=[
brief=[line=23
Description.]
docs=[line=25
@par Hook
init  //This one works
@since   1.0.0]
inbody=[line=-1
]
]
===========
-----------
CommentScanner: C:/path/bar.php:33
input=[
Description.

@since   1.0.0
]
-----------
CommentScanner: C:/path/bar.php:33
output=[
brief=[line=33
Description.]
docs=[line=35
@since   1.0.0]
inbody=[line=-1
]
]
===========
-----------
CommentScanner: C:/path/bar.php:52
input=[
Description.

@hook    init  //This one doesn't work
@since   1.0.0
]
-----------
CommentScanner: C:/path/bar.php:52
output=[
brief=[line=52
Description.]
docs=[line=54
@hook    init  //This one doesn't work
@since   1.0.0]
inbody=[line=-1
]
]
===========
C:/path/bar.php:54: warning: Found unknown command '\hook'
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem but didn't succeed, I see the hook in foobar2 and I don't get the message either. Which version of doxygen did you use? Do you have other settings in your doxygen configuration file different from the default settings?

Comment: I'm using DoxyGen 1.8.16. I've updated it to include most of the fields I've changed in the Doxyfile

Comment: Very strange, I still cannot reproduce the problem I see for foobar2 also a correct hook. I believe that you use version 1.8.16 but can you show the entire line that is given with `doxygen -v`?  Can you also supply the output you get with the above example for `doxygen -d commentscan`?

Comment: @albert Thanks for your help. Running `doxygen -v` returns this:
`1.8.16 (cfd73d5c4d1a66c620a3b7c08b72a3f3c3f94255*)`
And I've updated my post again. It seems the generic raw HTML I put in originally was not creating the same problem so I made it a bit closer to what I'm actually using to get the problem to trigger.

Comment: I did some tests, and it is not easy, but it looks like the single quote in `you've` is the trouble causer. Has to be investigated in doxygen further to find a solution. Best is to create an issue in the doxygen issue tracker: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks @albert! I'll do that. For now if anyone else finds this and has this issue, the work-around I'm using it to just move any functions with raw HTML to the bottom of the file.

Comment: I just though would it be possible to use `&apos;` instead of `'` or use `'<!--'-->`? (would also not be a workaround but probably nicer than moving the code and disturbing the flow ...)

Comment: Issue has been provided on github: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7368

Comment: Good call on `&apos;` Albert. I'll try that.